# Explain in English how this code iterates over a number

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

What does this code mean in English?  What is actually happening?

```
[int(n) for n in str(octal)]
```

It's part of a larger set of code/loop (see below.)  
What I understand is that it's taking in a number as the variable input to a function.  
This part of the code is allowing it to loop over the number.  
What I need to understand is the specifics of this line of code.  
`int(n)`, the for loop of `n` in `str(octal)`.  I need to understand it in English so that I can solve the rest of the code issue.  (Which I deliberately did not state.)  `octal` is the input variable to the entire function.

```
for each_number in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
    print (octal)
    print(n)
    
    # Check for each of the permissions values
    for value, letter in value_letters:
    
        if value >= value:
            print (value, letter)
            
            result += letter
            value -= value
            print (result)

        else:
            value -= 1
            result += "-"
            Print ("else statment", value, letter, result)
print("end of function")
print(" ")
return result
```

Comment: It's a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: Run the code, see the result. If that does not help, run smaller portions of it to get an idea.

Comment: I have been running the code, parts of it, and adding print statements in for the last five hours.  The entire code right now is about 25 lines long.  There is a reason that I'm looking for help, and Stack Overflow is one of the most difficult places to find any.

Answer (score 4):

`[int(n) for n in str(octal)]`

It's a list comprehension. It's usually helpful to read these right-to-left.

- `str(octal)`: Cast the variable `octal` to a string.
- `for n in str(octal)`: For every character `n` in the string:

  - `int(n)`: Cast the value to an integer.
- `[...]`: Return these results as a list.

So, the full expression returns a list of integers generated by iterating through every character in `str(octal)` and casting each character as an int.

Comment: That helps me.  Thank you.  Now I can understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

It's a list comprehension. Let's look at what this code might normally look like:

```
my_list = []
for n in str(octal):
    my_list.append(int(n))
```

Essentially, the list comprehension condenses this `for`-loop down into a single line. The statement before the `for` indicates what will be appended your output list. Then the `for` section indicates what you're looping over, just like the first line of a regular `for`-loop.

At a high level, this comprehension is separating the characters (presumably individual numbers) of the variable `octal` into a list. To do this, it's casting `octal` into a string so it can iterate over the individual characters, and then converting each character back into an int before putting it into the output list. So if `octal = 175` then your output list would be `[1, 7, 5]`

Comment: Thank you.  That's also helpful for me to understand.  I'm working on a Python class, and this part of the code was pre-written.  I've been working on understanding it for many, many hours because that's what I need to do to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [int(n) for n in str(octal)]
```

is the equivalent of:

```
lst = [] # Define an empty list
# We want every digit of octal, so we need to convert it into a string
for n in str(octal): # For every digit in the octal
    lst.append(int(n)) # Add the character converted into an integer to the list
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm beginning to see how I can solve the rest of the program / problem.  This part of the code was prewritten.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it's called list comprehension:

You can translate it as:

```
result = []

for n in str(octal):
    result.append(int(n))
```

So your code above can be written in a procedural way like:

```
for n in str(octal):
    each_number = int(n)
        print(octal)
        print(n)

    # Check for each of the permissions values
    for value, letter in value_letters:    
        if value >= value:
            print(value, letter)
        
            result += letter
            value -= value
            print(result)
        else:
            value -= 1
            result += "-"
            print("else statment", value, letter, result)
print("end of function")
print(" ")
return result
```

Looking at your code I don't see the reason for using list comprehension since 'each_number' is not used anywhere you the code.

Comment: The code posted was broken, it's part of why I was trying to understand it better.  I'm delighted to report that I just solved it!  The key statement should actually be "if each_number>=value"

The overall problem was about Octal and converting permissions.  It wasn't designed well since I had to actually learn about Octal before I could even start.